# Can't swipe up/down on iPhone when touch div with 'ovewrflow-x'

Tags: ios, css, iphone, touch, swipe

I have page with block of news, which scrolling horizontally.
When I try to scroll the page down and my touch starts on this block's area, page doesn't scroll. I can only scroll left or right. Tested on iPhone 6

Div has styles like this:

```
#news {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you cant find a solution give iscroll a go -- http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5